# Copy members of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct `Node` and `Box` given by

```
typedef struct Node{
    Particle p;
    Box box;
    struct Node *son[4];
}Node
```

and

```
typedef struct Box{
    double low[3];
    double up[3];
}Box
```

I have two functions `insert()` and `sonumb()` where I want to use these structures.

```
    void insert(Particle *p, Node *t){
        Box sonbox;
        int b=sonumb(&t->box, &sonbox, p);
        t->son[b]->box = sonbox; // <--- Produces Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    }

int sonumb(Box *box, Box *sonbox, Particle *p){ 
        int b=0;
        for(int d=0;d<3;d++){
            sonbox->up[d] = 0.5*box->up[d];
            sonbox->low[d] = 0.5*box->low[d];
            }
            b=1; // b=[0,3] just for this example
    }
```

`sonum()` returns an integer value `b`. `sonbox` represents after the call of `sonumb()` a smaller box inside of `t->box`. I return the right values for `sonbox` after the call. So `sonbox` is not empty. But if I want to copy those values like `t->son[b]->box = sonbox` I get an segmentatioin fault. What did I miss?

Comment: `sonbox` is not empty either way. Possible causes for a segfault are `b < 0 || b > 3` or `t->son[b]` being uninitialized.

Comment: Sorry, but please turn back to the [help] and read again how to ask "code not working" questions. It starts with providing a [mcve]. You have a code bug; but you are only showing parts of your code.

Comment: The `son` is struct pointer array and you need to allocate memory with `malloc` before you assign box each elements

Comment: `son[b]` mostly likely contains/evaluates to garbage. But we do not know, as you do not show the relevant code.

Comment: @StoryTeller You are right. Now I see my error. Thank you! I forgot to initialize `t->son[b]`.

Comment: @Samuel Hey can you paste the function `sonumb(&t->box, &sonbox, p)` body here so that we know if it actually returns an integer. What does it return if the `function` fails.

Comment: @Seek Addo I updated the example

Answer (score 1):

You have nearly certainly missed the allocation of `son` elements. In order for the expression `t->son[b]->box` to produce a valid target of an assignment, `t->son[b]` needs to be assigned a pointer to a valid `Node` structure. The pointer needs to point to some `Node` that you have previously allocated.

If child nodes are shared among nodes, this should be a `malloc`-ed node. This adds quite a bit of complexity, because deleting shared nodes is non-trivial. Two common approaches to working with shared nodes are to (1) allocate all nodes at once in a large array, and use them one-by-one as they become needed, and (2) add reference count to the `struct`, increment it when taking a pointer, and decrement it when the reference is no longer needed. The second approach is extremely difficult to implement; see if you can avoid it before committing to it.

On the other hand, if child nodes are owned exclusively by their parent, you have a very simple solution: allocate `Node` with `malloc` before the assignment of `son[b]` elements, and `free` them when you are done with the node:

```
Box sonbox;
int b=sonumb(&t->box, &sonbox, p);
t->son[b] = calloc(1, sizeof(Node)); // Allocate the node
t->son[b]->box = sonbox;
```

Use of `calloc` ensures that the memory of the `Node` is cleared prior to making other assignments. If this is not necessary, because you assign all members in the rest of your function, replace the call with `malloc`:

```
t->son[b] = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Comment: Why no asterisk? I got the code from a book where I try to understand the code. There an asterisk is used. Child nodes are owned exclusively by their parent.

Comment: @Samuel I see why the trick with placing the `Node` in the `struct` wouldn't work. See the edit.

Comment: I updated my question and added the function`sonumb()`. Does your answer still apply to it?

Answer (score 0):

adding to @dasblinkenlight's comment.

```
Box sonbox;  ---> This variable is on stack 
int b=sonumb(&t->box, &sonbox, p); --> content of t->box is COPIED to sonbox, not by reference but by value. 
t->son[b]->box = sonbox; // --> Assigning stack variable is incorrect, because it will vanish once you exit function. OR as @dasblinkenlight suggested pass the value but not the pointer.
```